# Why Composer install never works

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Since I'm on Symfony, I've been a lot in trouble with bundle integration with Composer. Very often I have this famous error :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

I've read on forums that it's an *minimum-stability* parameter issue, solvable by setting it at "dev" or "stable". None of them works for me.

I started, restarted again and again new projects and results are not there... I'm tired.

So anyone has any suggestion ? Does the order in the *require* matter ?

EDIT : Composer is uptodate and I work on Ubuntu

Comment: Post the *full* output. There should be an indication of what's missing in an earlier message.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/Dkm9qSZ2) while trying to install sonata user bundle whith [that](http://pastebin.com/yW7y0623) composer configuration. Hope you'll find something !

Comment: Never ever use `dev-master` as a version, use a specific **stable** version instead. That'll help you a lot :)

Comment: You mean using a specific version of a bundle (eg. v3.5.2) ?

Answer (score 1):

SonataUserBundle requires FosUserBundle version 1.3

https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle

You included FosUserBundle version 2.0.*. That's why composer tells you that you can only have one verision of FosUserBundle, not both. So either remove FosUserBundle requirements or remove SonataUserBundle.

Comment: I already try this but thanks for proposing. I just had another example : [I folow those instructions](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/develop/doc/reference/tutorials/install.html) and same error with Composer.